# Android: Detecting Long Click on PopupMenu Items

Tags: java, android, menu

I currently have a button that generates a popup menu and I'm trying to find a way to detect when an item within the menu has been long clicked. Once I detect the user has clicked and held on the menu item I want to prompt them to ask if they wish to delete the item.

I understand how to programatically remove menu items, ala the post here: [remove popup menu item programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435094/remove-popup-menu-item-programmatically). The problem i'm having is detecting the long click on a menu item.

As far as I know there is no setMenuOnItemLongClickListener(), only a setMenuOnItemClickListener(), so am I left to make a custom solution to detect long clicks on popupmenu items?

Answer (score 1):

Set action view to menu items and get them via [`getActionView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionView()). To this view you can attach long click listeners.

You can attach an action view to menu item through xml as well:

```
<item
    ...
    android:actionViewClass="<custom class>"
</item>
```

Comment: Could you kindly add a bit more code to describe how to set action view to menu items programatically? The menu's items are added during runtime so I have to set the action view programatically instead of via xml (and i'm not familiar with the process)

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446126/custom-action-view-cant-be-clicked